# Minecraft 1.8.8 gives error "Couldn't initialize twitch stream"?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I don't need twitch, so what do I do when this pops up?

```
24-09-15 21:22:38: Starting Launcher...
24-09-15 21:22:38: Online mode...
24-09-15 21:22:38: Checking Minecraft for updates...
24-09-15 21:22:38: Last checked for updates: less than an hour ago
24-09-15 21:22:38: Loading Launcher profiles...
24-09-15 21:22:38: Loading User profiles...
24-09-15 21:22:38: Loading versions list...
24-09-15 21:22:42: Loading Launcher profiles...
24-09-15 21:22:42: Loading User profiles...
24-09-15 21:22:42: Loading versions list...
24-09-15 21:22:44: Launching minecraft...
24-09-15 21:22:44: Something went wrong due unpacking tv\twitch\twitch-external-platform\4.5\twitch-external-platform-4.5-natives-windows-64.jar: Cannot read that as a ZipFile
24-09-15 21:22:44: Unpacking natives completed. Total recovered 10 files
24-09-15 21:22:44: Launch command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\\natives -cp C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\\libraries\oshi-project\oshi-core\1.1\oshi-core-1.1.jar;C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\jna\3.4.0\jna-3.4.0.jar;C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\platform\3.4.0\platform-3.4.0.jar;C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\\libraries\com\ibm\icu\icu4j-core-mojang\51.2\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar;C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\\libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\4.6\jopt-simple-4.6.jar;C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\\libraries\com\paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\codecjorbis-20101023.jar;C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\\libraries\com\paulscode\codecwav\20101023\codecwav-20101023.jar;C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\\libraries\com\paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\\libraries\com\paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar;C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\\libraries\com\paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar;C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\\libraries\io\netty\netty-all\4.0.23.Final\netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar;C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\17.0\guava-17.0.jar;C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.3.2\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar;C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\\libraries\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.9\commons-codec-1.9.jar;C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar;C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\\libraries\net\java\jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.2.4\gson-2.2.4.jar;C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\\libraries\com\mojang\authlib\1.5.21\authlib-1.5.21.jar;C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\\libraries\com\mojang\realms\1.7.24\realms-1.7.24.jar;C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.8.1\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar;C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.3\httpclient-4.3.3.jar;C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\\libraries\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3.2\httpcore-4.3.2.jar;C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.0-beta9\log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar;C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.0-beta9\log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar;C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl_util-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\\libraries\tv\twitch\twitch\6.5\twitch-6.5.jar;C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\\versions\1.8.8\\1.8.8.jar net.minecraft.client.main.Main --username violetassassin1124 --version Violeta --gameDir C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\ --assetsDir C:\Users\MDJC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\ --assetIndex 1.8 --uuid 57362f464412a2f32975408257cad494 --accessToken N3K00TD3KC4RC --userProperties {"luncher":["extremeLauncher"]} --userType mojang
24-09-15 21:22:45: [21:22:45] [Client thread/INFO]: Setting user: violetassassin1124
24-09-15 21:22:45: [21:22:45] [Client thread/INFO]: (Session ID is token:N3K00TD3KC4RC:57362f464412a2f32975408257cad494)
24-09-15 21:22:46: [21:22:46] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.4
24-09-15 21:22:48: [21:22:48] [Client thread/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default
24-09-15 21:22:48: If on Windows, make sure to provide all of the necessary dll's as specified in the twitchsdk README. Also, make sure to set the PATH environment variable to point to the directory containing the dll's.
24-09-15 21:22:48: [21:22:48] [Client thread/ERROR]: Couldn't initialize twitch stream
24-09-15 21:22:58: Minecraft closed.
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is that the game can't read the file responsible for Twitch. This means the game files are corrupted. Uninstalling, then reinstalling should fix this.

Comment: Can I not do that and try deleting something instead? I dont need Twitch.

Comment: The only way I can think of off the top of my head is to reinstall minecraft, it doesn't matter if you need twitch or not, the problem is that the game needs that file to launch, and it can't read it. Deleting the file would cause the same thing to happen, it would just change the error.

Comment: @user125678 - You should be able to keep your `saves` folder when you delete everything else in the `.minecraft` directory if that's what you're worried about

Comment: @user125678 Yeah Robotnik is correct just back up your save files.